# Redistributing Color in a RGB Image According to a Gaussian Distribution

Tags: image-processing, opencv, statistics, distortion

I haven't done this stuff in a while.

If I have an image $I$ I can equalize the histogram of the image using some opencv procedure, it's already defined. Equalizing an histogram means essentially to construct a function such that applied to each pixel $p \in I$ the new value it's like it had been sampled from a uniform distribution, assuming gray scale image for such explanation.

I don't remember if what I want to do has a specific name, but I kind of remember it was possible, but suppose I have a gaussian distribution (instead of a uniform one), say $\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, and I want to re-distribute the colors according to such distribution.

Is there a way to do this in opencv?

Comment: Where each pixel is 3 Dimensional Random Variable?

Comment: Yes, you can consider it like that.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't implemented it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you equalize the histogram you can think of your data as a stream of variables $ {X}_{i} $ where $ X \sim U \left[ 0, 1 \right] $.

Now all you need is to transform samples of Uniform Random Variable into Gaussian Variable.
You should do that by applying the Inverse CDF of Gaussian Distribution.
Basically applying the [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) method.
For Normal Distribution easy choice would be the [Box Muller Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).

After you apply this, you can just multiply each RGB pixel in the Cholesky Factorization of $ \Sigma $ to get exactly what you need.